# Почему файл /proc/net/rt_cache пустой?

Tags: linux, сеть, network-manager

Насколько знаю, в /proc/net/rt_cache хранится кеш маршрутизации. Сеть активна, файл пустой.
Сейчас этим управляет скрипт более высокого уровня?

Извините за глупый вопрос, хочу разобраться, что под капотом.

Comment: Если верить [этому](https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2011-ipv4-route-cache-linux) посту, подсистему router_cache выпилили из ядра в `3.6` и заменили на введённую в `2.6.39` [структуру](https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2017-ipv4-route-lookup-linux) в древовидном формате.

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо!